# Killing a process in linux

Tags: linux

```
server01:/# ps -ax | grep java

Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html

 7342 pts/3    Z      0:00 [java] <defunct>

 7404 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep java


server01:/# kill 7342

server01:/# ps -ax | grep java

Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html

 7342 pts/3    Z      0:00 [java] <defunct>

 7406 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep java


server01:/#
```

In the above I am using ps command to know the pid of the java process which is 7342 in the above case.

Then I killed that process using kill command.
But that is not killed because again ps command shows java process with pid 7342.

Should I use some else command to kill the process and Why kill is not able to kill the process

Thanx

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: The question is not about general programming, but about systems. Try superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux supports the BSD style switches to the `ps` command (without the leading - ... dash/hyphen).  If one supplies the hypen then the GNU coreutils version of `ps` (the one which is standard on mainstream Linux distributions) will attempt to interpret the switches as SysV compatible.  This is the source of your error.

I'd recommend using the BSD form of the switches and look up the `-o` option to specify an output format consisting ONLY of the PID of the matching processes.

Also you're attempting to kill a zombie.  As you've discovered that's a futile effort.  A zombie is a placeholder in the process able for a process which is already dead.  It remains in the process table until its parent process "reaps" its exit code.  If the parent never does a `wait()` system call then the entry will stay there until after the parent is killed, at which point the zombie (and any other orphaned processes) will be inherited by the `init` process.  The normal `init` under Linux (or any other form of UNIX) periodically reaps all dead processes (zombies).

Conceptually every process that exits on a UNIX/Linux system spends a small amount of time as a "zombie" ... that is there should always be a period of time between the process' termination and the time when some other process reads its exit value (even if only to discard it, as `init` does).

This question really should go on ServerFault

Comment: Addition: by running `ps auxf` you'll see what the parent process is. It's either blocked too, or not paying attention to it's children.

Answer (score 20):

try

## ps aux

then

## kill -1 PID_NUMBER

to ask program to close itself, if it dosn´t answer you can force it to close

## kill -9 PID_NUMBER

remember that using -9 to force program will finalize without asking and not saving anything
check: man kill
for more details

Comment: keep in mind that kill -9 should be your last resort as it doesn't let child processes of the process you are killing die. so they become zombie processes.

Comment: try this instead `lsof -wni tcp:3000 | xargs -I{} kill -9 {}`

Answer (score 5):

kill -9  can be used as a last resort to ensure the process dies.....

Answer (score 2):

`kill -9 $(pgrep -f keyword)`.

Kill pid(s) searched by 'KEYWORD';

Answer (score 1):

The process is listed as defunct. It's job is done and it's kept around because the parent process is still there. However, if the parent crashed or was killed by kill -9, there is no parent process, so the defunct process will kept around until reboot.
Defunct (or zombie) processes use only minimal resources, so you can keep them.

Solution: Either kill the parent or use `kill -9 <pid>`.

Comment: Or, if you are getting frustrated, `kill -KILL <pid>`

Comment: Thanx for the knoledge.
kill -9 <pid> is not working.
can u tell command to find parent process.

Answer (score 0):

```
kill $(pgrep [search pattern])
```

See if that works better.  You have to be either root or the process owner to kill a process.

Answer (score 0):

The java process has become a zombie process.  You should try sending the `SIGCHLD` signal to the parent process via `kill` to tell the parent process to reap the zombie child process.  Failing that, as mentioned by @Martin, you could kill the parent or `kill -9` the zombie process.