# how to close running process (Chrome) from task manager in Ubuntu

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, kill-process, task-management

while working on application, code execution caught in infinite loop like-

```
console.log('print');
```

and now it is running and running.
To close Chrome I tried everything which I can but no result.

finally I restart my machine to solve it, that took several minutes

The same (infinite looping) happen again and again, I looked for that like -

1. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/use-ctrl-alt-del-task-manager-ubuntu/
2. [Advanced Scheduled Process/Task Manager - Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443252/advanced-scheduled-process-task-manager-linux)
3. [Killing a process in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140105/killing-a-process-in-linux)

finally I got solution, wanted to share with all to save the time-

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution-

### 1. Machine info-

```
 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
```

2. Press windows Butoon-

[image]

3. type 'System Monitor', which will display one menu, click on that-
4. We will see list of all running process as-
   [image]
5. At bottom, we have button as 'end process', click on that which will show one popUp as-

[image]

click Ok and that task enjoy!!!
Hope will work for you too!!